# Just saved file but now cannot resave or change other files to same name

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-word-2013

I recently saved a file onto my USB (in F drive, last night) but I just tried to re-save it, where it said that there were permission issues and it wouldn't let me. I didn't put on a password or anything, just a 600-word word document that now won't work. I have researched, and, no, I didn't upgrade to 8.1 recently, but months ago. I did upload the document to a webmail, but I don't see why that would break it. I tried re saving it under another name, and then changing that name to the old name (script.docx), but now it says `You need administrator to rename this file` `Script2.docx` `Type: Microsoft Word Document` `Size: 1.37 MB` `Date modified: 27/11/2014 7:07 AM` with a [ADMIN]Continue, Skip, and Cancel button. (I am not admin on this computer). If the admin types in the password, it just comes up with another window that says `You need everyones permission to rename this file` - I click Try Again and it does nothing. When I go into the properties tab, there is no Security tab.

Comment: Are you trying to resave it to the USB drive? If so, have you tried removing and reinserting the USB drive? Checked it for errors? Rebooted the machine once? Try saving to a different drive -- does that work?

Comment: It seems that the original file didn't actually delete - but still why would it have had all those things and not let me save the original?

Comment: To me it sounds like the file system on the USB drive was/is corrupted, and/or the USB drive itself is dying. But you haven't answered any of my requests for clarification, and what you've said in your last comment is unclear (to me anyway).  I'll just bow out for now, good luck!

Comment: OK, @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 sorry - but it did fix it so thanks!

Comment: Ok now you've lost me even more.. :)  _What_ fixed it?!?!

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Pulling out the USB - ha it's the morning my brain is dead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19000/discussion-between-zoweb-and-c007).